# When I move Parent Bone another bone thats a child of that parent bone's object moves another direction

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

When I move Parent Bone another bone thats a child of that parent bone's object(the eyebrow) moves another direction. Im not the best explainer so heres a GIF

[image]

Comment: In what way is it moving, I mean, I can see the actual eyebrow moving, but I can't see the respective bone moving.

Comment: Most likely it is just a simple issue in the way the objects/bones were parented. Could you upload a blend file so that we can more easily take a look? It is very difficult to find the actual problem just from the post. However, just deleting the bone, adding it again, and re-parenting may fix the issue. It also looks like the other side is working so you could try deleting that whole side, mirroring the bone, then mirroring the parent. This is designed to work easily for symmetrical meshes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a so-called "double transformation": the bone moves the origin of the eyebrow (and all of its vertices follow) but the bone moves also the vertices away from the origin; so vertices move double the distance of what it's expected. Delete one of the two parenting (bone weight or object-bone parenting).